# Where did the usage of "around" to mean "about" come from?

Tags: etymology, prepositions

I work as a software engineer in the San Francisco Bay Area. Ever since starting work, I've noticed people using the word "around" where I'd say "about" or "on" for example:

"I have a question around metrics."

"Can you forward me the thread around developer engagement?"

"The company has been doing a lot of work around diversity and inclusion."

I feel like I never really heard this usage growing up in Pennsylvania, or in university in St. Louis, but it seems pervasive here. I particularly hear it from executives and product managers who work in the tech industry.

My questions are:

1. Is this common everywhere and I just failed to notice it?
2. If not, is it regional, industry-specific, or specific to a professional context?

[Google ngrams suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=questions+around&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquestions%20around%3B%2Cc0) that the phrase "questions around", which is a kind of maker for this usage, has really spiked in the last 20 years.

Comment: You apparently led a sheltered life.  [Figurative uses going back to 1912, if not earlier.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=questions+around%2C+centers+around&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquestions%20around%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccenters%20around%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I wish Hot Licks was mistaken, and I suspect huge numbers, if not the majority of people Ould rather follow herd fashion than think about what they're saying.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hot Licks, but I don't think the figurative "centers around" is quite the same usage as the quotes I gave. I think WS2's definition of "around" meaning "concerning" is much closer. The [older uses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22questions%20around%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1919&lr=lang_en) of "questions around" I see in the Google N-Grams search are mostly things like "asking questions around the table" which use "around" in the physical sense, so I figured it was worth asking a question (and was not disappointed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about here is OED (Oxford English Dictionary) prepositional sense B11. Its first reference is from 1897.

> 11. In reference or relation to; concerning, about.

1897   Punch 29 May 263/3   Essence of Parliament... Useful, but not precisely alluring, debate around Employers' Liability Bill.

1938   Wisconsin Libr. Bull. July 133/1   The rather outstanding feature throughout the> programs was the discussion around the larger problems of rural service.

1970   M. A. Cook Stud. in Econ. Hist. Middle East (1978) 278 (note)    The..publication..has stimulated discussion around pre-capitalist economic formations of the non-European type.

1991   B.> Moon Guide National Curriculum (ed. 3) vi. 75   At the heart of the> controversy was the debate around history as ‘content’ versus ‘skills’.

2013   Church Times 20 Sept. 34/4   Her biblical reflections..are thought provoking, and will..act as a stimulus to further biblical enquiry around the themes of justice and hospitality.

Comment: Well thanks, I guess, for pulling the rug out from under another of my pet peeves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find mention of this usage in the [*Online Etymology Dictionary*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/around).

I think the closest usage in the [*American Heritage Dictionary*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=around) would be:

> 7. In such a way as to have a basis or center in: *an economy focused around farming and light industry.*

And in the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> 2. c. Used to describe a situation in terms of the relation between people, actions, or events: *It was he who was attacking her, not the other way around.*